# Sumif Vertical & Horizontal Criteria in Excel / Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on employee scorecards and have hit a roadblock.  I need to sumif both vertical and horizonal criteria.  The horizonal criteria would be a lookback from a date.  For example looking up average sales revenue for John Doe for the last 3 months and/or last year based on a date of the current scorecard.

Here an example of the data:

[Image of the Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuHtC.png)

The examples I have seen are not using dynamic date ranges.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance, Phil

Comment: First decide if you will use Excel or Googlesheets. Once you have made your decision edit the tags appropriately.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I agree with both volunteer contributors above. Your image may tell *you* something, but we don't know your business, your goal or even where specifically to look for what you are trying to do. And even if all of that were clear, an image does not provide a testing ground with live data around which to build and test formulas. It's doubtful that any of the volunteers here will spend the time to open their own new spreadsheet, hand-enter all of your data, figure out a solution and then explain it. Help us to help you: share a link to a copy of the spreadsheet (names sanitized if you like).

Comment: My preference is Google sheets.

Comment: @Erik Tyler ,  I completely grasp your points.  I am new to stackoverflow for help.  I typically have been able to find solutions without needing to post.  My preference is Google sheets.  I have opened up the file for help.  the link is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NNuHdvtikgnTjDfsCFILd36BLFmRk_werQTcD6BY-Wc/edit?usp=sharing   What I am trying to do in cell PM Scorecard cell C15 = sum from the Data-WIP worksheet A121:D142 based on the employee name in sheet: PM Scorecard cell A2 matching column A and the range of this year to date based on the Cell PM Scorecard E3.